# Populate Dropdownlist in Dotnet Core MVC - Parse from dynamic JSON Product URL

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

**Sample JSON File :**

```
{ "products" : [{ "Name": "Cheese", "Price" : 2.50, "Location": "Refrigerated foods"},{ "Name": "Crisps", "Price" : 3, "Location": "the Snack isle"},  { "Name": "Pizza", "Price" : 4, "Location": "Refrigerated foods"},  { "Name": "Chocolate", "Price" : 1.50, "Location": "the Snack isle"},  { "Name": "Self-raising flour", "Price" : 1.50, "Location": "Home baking"},  { "Name": "Ground almonds", "Price" : 3, "Location": "Home baking"}]}
```

**Controller.cs Code**

```
 public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        //var jsonUrlProducts = webClient.DownloadString(@"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdn/fetch-examples/master/fetch-json/products.json");
        var jsonUrlProducts = webClient.DownloadString(@"C:\Users\NatarajanS\source\repos\KC_EC_WebSite_1\KC_EC_WebSite_1\wwwroot\lib\JSON\Json_F3.json");

        var dictProducts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonUrlProducts);

        ViewData["selectedProductTextDict"] = dictProducts;             
     
        return View();
    }
```

**Index.cshtml Code:**

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddlProductByText",
       new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["selectedProductTextDict"], "Value", "Key"))
```

{ "products" : [{ "Name": "Cheese", "Price" : 2.50, "Location": "Refrigerated foods"}] }

I need to Populate My Dropdownlist with Object key Names. Example from above JSON file .. **Name,Price,Location**

But the above code populates me root object name **products** only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dropdownlist values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WCVQ.png) As what Atabai said,you need create a model to map the json.For your json,the model design should be:

```
public class Test
{
    public List<Product> products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //....
    var dictProducts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(jsonUrlProducts);

    ViewData["selectedProductTextDict"] = dictProducts.products;
    return View();
}
```

View(e.g populate the name list):

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlProductByText",
      new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["selectedProductTextDict"], "Name", "Name"))
```

Result:

[image]

**Update:**

If you just want to display Name,Price,Location,check the following code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
       //...
        var dictProducts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,object>>(jsonUrlProducts);
        var data =(JArray)dictProducts["products"];
        Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (JObject obj in data.Children())
        {
            foreach (JProperty prop in obj.Children())
            {
                string key = prop.Name.ToString();
                string value = prop.Value.ToString();
                dic.Add(key, value);
            }
            break;
        }          
        ViewData["selectedProductTextDict"] = dic;
        return View();
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlProductByText",
      new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["selectedProductTextDict"], "Value", "Key"))
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. My Task is i need to populate dropdownlist with key names only ** Name,Price,Location **  from the example product json

Comment: key 'products' was replaced by key 'CO' in the below file. It works fine when i replace products by CO. But its not good to  hard code like this. Is there any way of getting dynamic key from the dictionary.     {"CO": [{"product-name": "MEN'S BETTER THAN NAKED&trade; JACKET","product-image-url": "http://images.thenorthface.com/is/image/TheNorthFace/236x204_CLR/mens-better-than-naked-jacket-AVMH_LC9_hero.png",
  "header-top-right-text": "Shop All","header-top-left-text": "Men's","product-url": "http://www.thenorthface.com/catalog/sc-gear/men-39-s-better-than-naked-8482-jacket.html"}]}

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rena. Your code working fine. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: key 'products' was replaced by key 'CO' in the below file. It works fine when i replace products by CO. But its not good to  hard-code like this. Is there any way of getting dynamic key from the dictionary.  {"CO": [{"product-name": "MEN'S BETTER THAN NAKED&trade; JACKET","product-image-url": http://images.thenorthface.com/is/image/TheNorthFace/236x204_CLR/mens-better-than-naked-jacket-AVMH_LC9_hero.png",
  "header-top-right-text": "Shop All",
  "header-top-left-text": "Men's",
  "product-url": "http://www.thenorthface.com/catalog/sc-gear/men-39-s-better-than-naked-8482-jacket.html"
 }]
}

Comment: It seems you do not want to specify the key name,right?

Comment: Try this:`var data =(JArray)dictProducts.Values.First();`.

Comment: It works like a charm.Thanks a lot for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create class object and use it, like below code :

```
    public class Product    {
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public double Price { get; set; } 
        public string Location { get; set; } 
    }
```

it help's you to access to all props.

Comment: thanks for your quick response.  My Task is i i  need to populate dropdownlist with key names only ** Name,Price,Location **  from the example product json